# Как создать переход на следующую цифру при умножении?

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, for, range

Создаю "таблицу умножения". Необходимо чтобы  при переходе на следующую цифру начинался отчёт от неё. (от 2х2 до 2х9, от 3х3 до 3х9, от 4х4 до 4х9 и т. д.)
Не знаю, что нужно подписать для получения необходимого результата, заранее спасибо.

```
for tab in range(2, 10):
    for chi in range(2, 10):
        print(tab, "*", + chi, " = ", + tab * chi)
    print('#'*14)
```

Comment: очень просто - нужно использовать ее в качестве нижней границы внутреннего цикла

Comment: Это я понял, а как написать правильно и внедрить в код?

Comment: for chi in range(tab, 10)

Comment: А, серьёзно... Спасибо, ребят